# How to terminate an asynchronous function in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How would it be possible to terminate this method / download function?

```
private void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://google.com/test.zip"), @"test.zip");

}
```

Basically cancel the download function

Comment: Read the Remarks section of the MSDN Library article for the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this: `webClient.CancelAsync();`

Comment: How would you call this from an external method?

Comment: @James: You need to save a reference to your WebClient instance somewhere, instead of letting it go out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CancelAsync`, from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.cancelasync.aspx) :

> **Remarks**
>
> If an operation is pending, this method calls Abort on the
>   underlying WebRequest. When you call CancelAsync, your application
>   still receives the completion event associated with the operation. For
>   example, when you call CancelAsync to cancel a DownloadStringAsync
>   operation, if you have specified an event handler for the
>   DownloadStringCompleted event, your event handler receives
>   notification that the operation has ended. To learn whether the
>   operation completed successfully, check the Cancelled property on the
>   base class of DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs in the event data object
>   passed to the event handler. If no asynchronous operation is in
>   progress, this method does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Call the `CancelAsync()` method.